# Parsing expressions using idiomatic C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm a C++ programmer using [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/) problems to learn C(99). This is my solution to the problem [CMEXPR](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CMEXPR/), where the goal is to read a valid expression (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/` only) from input and write it on output with superfluous parentheses removed.

The code yields correct answer according to the online judge (got an `AC`). My question is whether there are any C++-isms in the code and if so, what would be a more idiomatic C way of expressing them. Basically, I don't want to write C++ code in C (just like I don't like C code written in C++).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//#define TESTING

#ifdef TESTING
  #define TEST_ASSERT(maCond) do { if (!(maCond)) { printf("%d: %s\n", __LINE__, #maCond); exit(1); } } while (0)
  #define TEST_ASSERT_MSG(maCond, maFormat, maMsg) \
    do { \
      if (!(maCond)) { printf("%d: %s: '" maFormat "'\n", __LINE__, #maCond, (maMsg)); exit(1); } \
    } while (0)
  #define IF_TESTING(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
  #define TEST_ASSERT(maCond) do {} while (0)
  #define TEST_ASSERT_MSG(maCond, maFormat, maMsg) do {} while(0)
  #define IF_TESTING(...)
#endif


enum ParsingContext
{
  CONTEXT_FIRST_TERM
  , CONTEXT_ADDITIVE_EXPRESSION
  , CONTEXT_NONFIRST_TERM
};


struct ExprNode
{
  char type;
  struct ExprNode *child[2];
};


struct NodeMemory
{
  struct ExprNode data[MAX_NODE_COUNT];
  struct ExprNode *end;
};


struct ExprNode* createNode(struct NodeMemory *mem, char type)
{
  struct ExprNode *node = mem->end++;
  TEST_ASSERT(mem->end - mem->data <= MAX_NODE_COUNT);
  node->type = type;
  IF_TESTING(
    node->child[0] = node->child[1] = NULL;
  )
  return node;
}


struct ExprNode* moveToChild(
  struct NodeMemory * restrict mem
  , struct ExprNode * restrict node
  , size_t idxChild
  , char newParentType
)
{
  struct ExprNode * result = createNode(mem, newParentType);
  result->child[idxChild] = node;
  return result;
}


char readChar(const char * restrict * restrict in)
{
  char c = **in;
  ++*in;
  return c;
}


void writeChar(char * restrict * restrict out, char c)
{
  **out = c;
  ++*out;
}


struct ExprNode* parse(
  struct NodeMemory * restrict mem
  , const char * restrict * restrict in
  , struct ExprNode * restrict root
  , enum ParsingContext context
)
{
  TEST_ASSERT(root != NULL);
  bool skipStart = (context == CONTEXT_NONFIRST_TERM);
  // Left operand
  if (!skipStart) {
    switch (**in) {
      case '(':
        ++*in;
        root = parse(mem, in, root, CONTEXT_FIRST_TERM);
        TEST_ASSERT_MSG(**in == ')', "%c", **in);
        ++*in;
        break;
      default:
        TEST_ASSERT_MSG(
          **in != ')'
          && **in != '+'
          && **in != '-'
          && **in != '*'
          && **in != '/'
          && **in != '\n'
          , "%c", **in
        );
        root->type = readChar(in);
        break;
    }
  }
  for (;;) {
    // Operator
    if (!skipStart) {
      switch (**in) {
        case '\n':
        case ')':
          TEST_ASSERT(root != NULL);
          TEST_ASSERT(root->type != '.');
          return root;
        case '+':
        case '-':
          if (context == CONTEXT_NONFIRST_TERM) {
            TEST_ASSERT(root != NULL);
            TEST_ASSERT(root->type != '.');
            return root;
          }
          TEST_ASSERT(
            (context == CONTEXT_ADDITIVE_EXPRESSION)
            ==
            (root->type == '+' || root->type == '-')
          );
          context = CONTEXT_ADDITIVE_EXPRESSION;
          root = moveToChild(mem, root, 0, readChar(in));
          break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
          if (context == CONTEXT_ADDITIVE_EXPRESSION) {
            TEST_ASSERT(root->child[1]->type != '.');
            root->child[1] = moveToChild(mem, root->child[1], 0, readChar(in));
            root->child[1] = parse(mem, in, root->child[1], CONTEXT_NONFIRST_TERM);
            continue; // Parsed up to next operator or teminator
          }
          root = moveToChild(mem, root, 0, readChar(in));
          break;
        default:
          TEST_ASSERT(false);
          break;
      }
    }
    skipStart = false;
    // Right operand
    switch (**in) {
      case '(':
        ++*in;
        root->child[1] = parse(mem, in, createNode(mem, '.'), CONTEXT_FIRST_TERM);
        TEST_ASSERT_MSG(**in == ')', "%c", **in);
        ++*in;
        break;
      default:
        TEST_ASSERT_MSG(
          **in != ')'
          && **in != '+'
          && **in != '-'
          && **in != '*'
          && **in != '/'
          && **in != '\n'
          , "%c", **in
        );
        root->child[1] = createNode(mem, readChar(in));
        break;
    }
  }
}


void serialiseTree(const struct ExprNode * restrict node, char * restrict * restrict out, char parentType, bool isLeftChild)
{
  IF_TESTING(
    if (!node) {
      writeChar(out, 'N');
      return;
    }
  )
  TEST_ASSERT(
    parentType == '+'
    || parentType == '-'
    || parentType == '*'
    || parentType == '/'
  );
  bool paren = false;
  switch (node->type) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
      paren = (
        parentType == '*'
        || parentType == '/'
        || (parentType == '-' && !isLeftChild)
      );
      break;
    case '*':
    case '/':
      paren = (parentType == '/' && !isLeftChild);
      break;
    default:
      writeChar(out, node->type);
      return;
  }
  if (paren) {
    writeChar(out, '(');
  }
  serialiseTree(node->child[0], out, node->type, true);
  writeChar(out, node->type);
  serialiseTree(node->child[1], out, node->type, false);
  if (paren) {
    writeChar(out, ')');
  }
}


void createTree(struct NodeMemory *mem)
{
  char expr[MAX_INPUT_SIZE + 2];
  fgets(expr, sizeof(expr), stdin);
  const char *in = expr;
  if (*in == '\n') {
    fputs(expr, stdout);
    return;
  }
  struct ExprNode *root = parse(mem, &in, createNode(mem, '.'), CONTEXT_FIRST_TERM);
  TEST_ASSERT(*in == '\n');
  TEST_ASSERT(root != NULL);
  char *out = expr;
  serialiseTree(root, &out, '+', true);
  *out++ = '\n';
  *out = 0;
  TEST_ASSERT(out - expr < sizeof(expr));
  fputs(expr, stdout);
}


void runCase(void)
{
  struct NodeMemory mem;
  mem.end = mem.data;
  createTree(&mem);
}


int main(void) {
  int caseCount;
  fscanf(stdin, "%d\n", &caseCount);
  for (int idxCase = 0; idxCase < caseCount; ++idxCase) {
    runCase();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- I use [ideone](http://ideone.com/grzWm1) for developing this code, so that's why I'm using my own assertions instead of built-in `assert()`; an "unusual termination" wouldn't be too helpful.
- There's no error checking on input because in the context of the online judge, input correctness is guaranteed.
- `NodeMemory` is used to avoid overhead of dynamic allocation in presence of a known maximum problem size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These comments are not really related to writing "idiomatic C", merely things I noticed in your code.

- Your handling of commas in lists is odd:

  ```
  enum ParsingContext {
      CONTEXT_FIRST_TERM
      , CONTEXT_ADDITIVE_EXPRESSION
      , CONTEXT_NONFIRST_TERM
  };

  struct ExprNode* moveToChild(
      struct NodeMemory * restrict mem
      , struct ExprNode * restrict node
      , size_t idxChild
      , char newParentType
      )
  ```

  I have never seen things written like that and don't see any advantage
  over the normal use:

  ```
  enum ParsingContext {
      CONTEXT_FIRST_TERM,
      CONTEXT_ADDITIVE_EXPRESSION,
      CONTEXT_NONFIRST_TERM
  };

  struct ExprNode* moveToChild(struct NodeMemory * restrict mem,
                               struct ExprNode * restrict node,
                               size_t idxChild,
                               char newParentType)
  ```
- Your macros and their invocation should allow a semicolon to be placed where
  expected.  Otherwise, syntax-aware editors can get confused and mess up the
  indentation:

  ```
      IF_TESTING(
          node->child[0] = node->child[1] = NULL;
          )
          return node;
  ```

  Better to move the ; out of the bracket:

  ```
      IF_TESTING((node->child[0] = node->child[1] = NULL));
      return node;
  ```
- Your asserts that check against a list of chars could be simpler with
  `strchr` (also I find the placement of the && here to be distracting, but I
  know some people like it that way):

  ```
  TEST_ASSERT_MSG(
     **in != ')'
     && **in != '+'
     && **in != '-'
     && **in != '*'
     && **in != '/'
     && **in != '\n'
     , "%c", **in
     );
  ```

  Neater (?):

  ```
  TEST_ASSERT_MSG(!strchr(")+-*/\n", **in), "%c", **in);
  ```
- I always find passing double pointers to be awkward and confusing, so I
  avoid it if possible.  In this case it seems that you could read and write
  the input/output string directly to/from stdin/out as you go, replace
  `readChar` and `writeChar` with `fgetc` and `fputc` and pass
  `stdin`/`stdout` around in instead of `in` and `out` (or just use the
  `stdin`/`stdout` globals).
- Note that using an `assert` to check for exceeding the available memory is
  incorrect.  This should be an explicit `if` and `exit`.

  ```
  TEST_ASSERT(mem->end - mem->data <= MAX_NODE_COUNT);
  ```

Comment: +1, thanks. Nice use of `strchr()`, wouldn't have thought about that. The out-of-memory assert is due to the SPOJ specifics - I know the maximum input size, so running out of space can only be a bug in the algorithm. As for the `,` and `&&`, I find list modifications usually happen at the end more than at the beginning, and this placement makes the last line syntax non-special.

Comment: About per-character input; wouldn't that be noticably slower than reading the string at once and then parsing it?

Comment: With your `,` and `&&` isn't the first line syntax now "special" (ie. it doesn't have a `,` etc)? Per-char reading speed noticeable to whom? Unless you are operating on really huge input strings I doubt the speed difference will be noticeable to a user.

Comment: Yes, the first line is special. But as I said, experience tells me one modifies a list's end more often than its beginning (adding params etc.). Per-char: it's true that on 250-char strings (even if there are tens of thousands of them), I was probably overly cautious. Thanks again.